# Are these two python if statements same or not?

Tags: python

```
data = [] if data is None else list(data)
```

```
data = list(data) if data else []
```

Someone asked if these two are same or not, and which one I preferred. I told him they are same, but he didn't seem to be satisfied by the answer. So, are they different or same, and which one do you prefer?

Comment: See [What is Truthy and Falsy, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

You can reverse the first one, then you have

```
data = list(data) if data is not None else []
```

vs.

```
data = list(data) if data else []
```

Or you can reverse the 2nd one, then you have

```
data = [] if not data else list(data)
```

vs.

```
data = [] if data is None else list(data)
```

So your question boils down to

- whether `if data is not None` is the same as `if data` or alternatively
- whether `if data is None` is the same as `if not data`.

These are semantically different:

- `if data is None` is only true if data is `None`,
- `if not data` is true if data has any "falsey" value: e. g. `None`, `0`, `""`, `False`, `()`, `{}`, `[]` etc.

Comment: The last line looks like my answer. Thanks

Comment: 'resp.' is not used in English, if you're trying to use it as the equivalent of German 'bzw.' Can you rewrite your answer without it?